# Espacio blanco sobre un video cover (solo pasa en safari, no google chrome)

Tags: html, css, video

Tengo este problema en un sitio web, pero solo sucede cuando lo abro en safari: queda un espacio blanco arriba y abajo de un video que puse como cover.

Aquí va el código:

**HTML**

```
<div>
<video autoplay loop poster="images/inicio.png"> 
<source src="video/video.webm" type="video/webm"> 
<source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>   
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
video{ 
width: 100% !important; 
height: auto !important; 
min-height: 30%; 
display: table;
background:rgb(242,242,242) url('images/inicio.png') center bottom   no-repeat; 
background-size:100% auto;
margin-bottom: -4px;
z-index: 1;
```

Ya trate con todos los tipos de **display** y nada lo arregla.

Imagen del problema: [image: foto]

La url de la pagina es http://www.josefinaechenique.com/videos.html

Comment: prueba de cambiar `display: table;` a `display: block;`

Comment: Ya utilizaste el inspector para tratar de encontrar el elemento o el estilo que lo genera?